# Is there a way of hiding the telephone country code in Android Studio

Tags: android, country-codes

I need to add a country code to phone numbers to dial it from Android, but I would like to display the phone numbers without the country code. I can get the dialler working using `setText()` for the phone number (with country code) in Java and adding Autolink in the XML.

However I can't seem to find a way of displaying the phone number without the country code i.e. when using `<a href=` you can have different text to the actual hyperlink.

So I want to display `01234 567890`, but dial `+441234567890`.

I've tried using this HTML in a string but it doesn't work:

```
<a href="tel:+441234567890">01234 567890</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove first three characters of your string line:

```
numberString.substring(3);
```

and it will return you: 
`01234 567890`

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: FYI: `three letters` -> `three characters` as `letter` is a `character` but `character` is not neccesary a `letter`.

Comment: so it isn't a solution of this problem? :(

Comment: nah, I was just talking about naming things, if you cut `1` and say you cut a `letter` it will still work :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a `ClickableSpan`:

```
final SpannableString span = new SpannableString("01234 567890");
final ClickableSpan onClick = new ClickableSpan() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View textView) {
        //Launch your Intent to dial the number, with whatever number you like
    }
    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
        super.updateDrawState(ds);
    }
};
span.setSpan(onClick, 0, span.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view);
tv.setText(span);
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
textView.setHighlightColor(Color.GREEN);
```

You may need to add `clickable:true` in your XML as well.

Or, if your `TextView` just contains the number, you can set a click listener on the entire `TextView` and launch your dial from there